# Why is table 'data' unavailable within function

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I'm working on reproducing a live filter box with handsontable based on the built in search functionality at http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/demo-search-for-values.html.

Right Now I'm working with the simplest use case (http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/uL3L4teL/) from the docs.

As explained in the docs, In this code if you enter a search string, you get the matching cells outputted to the console using the following function:

```
         Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(searchFiled, 'keyup', function (event) {
                var queryResult = hot.search.query(this.value);

                console.log(queryResult);
                hot.render();
```

I've modified this like so:

```
            function getRowsFromObjects(queryResult) {
                rows = [];
                for (var i = 0, l = queryResult.length; i < l; i++) {
                    debugger
                    rows.push(queryResult[i].row);
                }
                console.log('rows',rows);
                return rows;
            }

            Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(searchFiled, 'keyup', function (event) {

                var queryResult = hot.search.query(this.value);

                console.log(queryResult);
                rows = getRowsFromObjects(queryResult);
                hot.render();
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/uL3L4teL/1/

The reason for this is to grab the row numbers of the cells that match. 
My plan is to then grab the associated data rows and re-render the table. But the variable 'data' (best seen in the fiddles) does not appear to be available inside the Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(searchFiled, 'keyup', function (event) function). How can I provide access to this within the function?

Comment: I've just tried logging it out in the fiddle and it works fine.

Comment: [Handsontable.getData()](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.3/Core.html#getData) ?

Comment: mark_c, I'm pretty new to JS, Can you tell me more about what you did?

Comment: James, that seems to be working , thanks, do you want to add it as an answer?